# How do I configure win-p to chose the correct displays?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

Win-p can change between different display configurations quickly, which is nice. However, exactly what configurations it can switch between seems to be quite random.

I used to have a monitor and a TV connected and win-p changed one or the other quickly. (It called the computer "projector" and the TV "computer" though.)

Now I bought another monitor and win-p no longer does *anyhing* useful.

Is there any way to configure one monitor to be the "computer" and the other to be the "projector"?

I'd really be "happy" with just being able to toggle between single monitor "game mode" and two monitor "browser mode". TV only "couch mode" would be a bonus.